# Automapper and upgrading to net standard 2.1 with multi target to 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper, .net-standard-2.1

Im busy upgrading a .net fx 4.7 project which is a class library to .net standard 2.1. This is an existing solution that is in 4.7 and is multi layered. I have upgraded for the most part the data layer but had to multi target .net standard 2.1 and 4.7 due to EF6. Im at the business layer and there is extensive use of automapper. It looks like automapper dropped 4.x support and now supports .net standard 2.1. Im thinking for now I could multi target the business later dll and some how load the older automapper using an if def and load the new one if the build tartgets .net standard 2.1. Is this possible?